# How to make the phantomjs browser visible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, electron, headless-browser

I know that it is sound strange. The point is that I want a NodeJS app to control the browser. On the same time, I want to see the browser and be able to interact with it it, and see what it is doing in real-time.

If it is not possible in PhantomJS, there is any other way to control a dedicated browser from NodeJS. (dedicated browser I mean that I don't want to use my own personal Chrome)

**Usage Case:** For example, I want to test an app that requires "login". I don't want to test the login process. 
So I need to "login" manually, (let the browser to save the cookies), and then I will be able to run the tests using the same cookies of the logged in user.

**In other words:** Is it possible to interact with as browser that controlled by NodeJS? I need the option to show the browser and hide it (so it will work from desktop and headless servers)

Comment: After seen the answers, I don't like the title of my question. it is generally about any NodeJS headless browser module not specific about PhantomJS. Do you have any other suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

PhantomJS is a headless browser which means there is nothing to show.

Fortunately there **are** other options that may fit your workflow

---

[NightmareJS](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#api) is using Electron which is based on Google Chrome browser. You may make the browser visible:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');       
var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });
```

---

[SlimerJS](https://slimerjs.org/) is always visible, it's syntax-compatible with PhantomJS.

Comment: Is it possible to change this property in runtime?

Comment: Haven't tried doing that, don't think it is. Why would you want to?

Comment: Yes. it is possible: https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/907 It is use Electron behind the scene,

Comment: Nice find. But please note that even if you hide it, NightmareJS is still not truly headless and you'll need xvfb or xvfb-run to run it on a server.

Comment: By the way, Silmer cannot help me. I need to interact with pages, that I cannot add scripts to it while testing.

Comment: Ahhh. It's not truly headless. So still searching for a solution

Comment: "that I cannot add scripts to it while testing" can't catch your meaning

Comment: "not truly headless. So still searching" but you won't be able to interact with truly headless browser. It's one or another.